# Show the Hölder Inequality from the young Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to show the Hölder inequality:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}{u_iv_i}\leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N}{(u^p_i)}\right)^{1/p}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{N}{(v^q_i)}\right)^{1/q}$$
I have the young inequality:$$uv\leq \frac{u^p}{p}+\frac{u^q}{q}$$
Applying $$u=x_i/||x||_p$$ and 
$$v=y_i/||y||_p'$$ to the young inequality:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\frac{x_iy_i}{||x||_p||y||_q}}\leq \frac{1}{p}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{N}{\frac{x^p_i}{||x||^p_p}}\right)+\frac{1}{q}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{N}{\frac{y^q_i}{||y||^q_q}}\right)$$
and now what am I doing?

Answer (score 1):

You mix a bit notations, but you are almost done :
$$\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{x_i^p}{\|x\|_p^p}+\frac{1}{q}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{y_i^q}{\|y\|^q_q}=1.$$

Applying the fact that $$\sum_{i=1}^Nu_iv_i=\frac{1}{\|x\|_p\|y\|_q}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_iy_i,$$
allows you to conclude.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: :is it correct that $\left( \sum_{i=1}^{N}{\frac{x^p_i}{||x||^p_p}}\right)=1$ and $\left( \sum_{i=1}^{N}{\frac{y^q_i}{||y||^q_q}}\right)=1$ because $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$?

Comment: Yes $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i^p}{\|x\|_p^p}=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{y_i^q}{\|y\|_q^q}=1$, but this is independant from $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.